# What does "nothing the director Paul Greengrass could have shown later on would have made me regret watching the film" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> There's an action sequence in *Jason Bourne* that is a thing of such cinematic beauty that **nothing the director Paul Greengrass could have shown later on would have made me regret watching the film.** ([Source.](http://www.thehindu.com/todays-paper/tp-features/tp-cinemaplus/snoop-god/article8954040.ece))

Help me understand the portion that is in bold.

Comment: Welcome to ELL. Please specify which part you find confusing. Also, please include sources (like a link) whenever possible. - [From Review](http://ell.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/44118).

Comment: The part under inverted commas. Source: The Hindu, 7th August 2016. Page 2. First article.

Comment: @user141202 There are no "inverted commas" in the text you cite.

Comment: I put it to highlight the portion.

Comment: I imagine you are confused by "nothing ...  could have shown...would have made me regret".    Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Can you break it down into simpler English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**could have shown**  refers to a past conditional possibility, something that did not occur but might have occurred

**would have made me regret** refers to the result of that possibility if it had been real, not merely hypothetical.

That action sequence was so good, even if later on in the movie there had been something objectionable (very boring or ridiculous, say) I would still not regret watching the film.

**Nothing** adds great emphasis to the remark because it is an extreme statement: No thing...

**nothing...he could have shown**

It is *impossible* that he could have shown *something* which would have made me regret watching the movie.

That action sequence was so good that it became *impossible* for him to do *any thing* to spoil the movie for me.

Comment: nothing the director Paul Greengrass could have shown later on. Please explain me this sentence.

Comment: later on = afterwards, later in the movie.

Comment: Nothing as no thing, that clarifies everything. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

This sentence means that the action sequence mentioned is of such high quality – it is so good – that even if the remainder of the film had been awful, the author would still have enjoyed the film because of that action sequence. If the film had been bad, the author may have regretted watching it because it would have been a one- or two-hour waste of time.

The author says that Paul Greengrass was showing him something because a film director is in charge of turning the (textual) script into the scenes that are shown in the movie, so watching a movie is being shown the film director's vision of the script.

Comment: nothing the director Paul Greengrass could have shown later on. Please explain me this sentence

Comment: @user141202: As explained in my second paragraph, Paul Greengrass is "showing" the viewer the scenes in the film. "Nothing... shown later on" means that everything the director had put in the film after (*later on from*) the action sequence could have been awful and the reviewer would still have enjoyed the film because of how good the action sequence was.